# Can someone explain me this recursive method?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, logic

This code counts the number 7 of your input. This is the code method:

```
    public static int count7(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n % 10 == 7) {
        return 1  + count7 (n/10);
    }
    else {
        return count7(n/10);
    }
}
```

What does the else-if statement and else do? Thank you so much.

Comment: `n%10 == 7` returns true when the last digit of the number is a 7. So if the last number is a seven add 1 otherwise don't add 1...

Comment: what do you think the if-else  or else-if does?

Comment: Use a debugger and watch the flow of the code. In case you don't know how to use one: you'll have to learn that anyways, if you want to learn coding. And there are plenty of resources on that topic available

Comment: This counts the number of digits in a decimal which are `7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (n % 10 == 7)` if the remainder is 7 lets take example `n=17` so `17%10` you are going to get 7 so add 1 means count that you have found 7 if you have not found then go to the else part and this time call by dividing it suppose this time n=28 clearly there is no 7 in this number so it will go to else if condition and it is going to be fail it will go to the else part and it will call the method by dividing n to 10 for the next iteration.

Comment: This is the answer that i want to see. Others are just explaining the flow of the code but not the logic. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (n == 0) {
    return 0;
```

There are no 7s in 0, so return 0.

```
} else if (n % 10 == 7) {
```

checks if the least significant digit of the number is 7. If that's the case, the total number of 7s is 1 + the number of 7s in the number you get by removing that digit (by dividing the number by 10) :

```
     return 1  + count7 (n/10);

} else {
```

If the least significant digit is not 7, the number of 7s is the number of 7s in n/10 :

```
    return count7(n/10);
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the `n == 0` check is the [Recursion Termination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_termination) base case?

Answer (score 1):

This is a **recursive method**.

The first `if` is **the base case**, i.e, if the numbers is 0, then it returns 0.

The `else if` checks if the digit is 7. If it is, then get the answer to the remaining digits (whether they have any 7s) using the same method, add 1 to it, and return the value.

The last else just removes one digit, and calls the method for the remaining digits.

Answer (score 0):

This method counts the total amount of the digit 7 in a given number.

`n % 10 == 7` inspects the least significant digit, and if it equals 7, then add 1 to the sum.

In any case, the algorithm goes on with the other digits by taking `n / 10`, which actually removes the least significant digit, and then calls the method recursively. As the number is decreasing with 1 digit with each call and the stop trigger `n == 0` makes the method eventually stop, the final returned number counts the sevens in the initial number.

Example

```
count7(172) = 0 + count7(17) = 0 + 1 + count7(1) = 0 + 1 + 0 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The function simply counts the total number of appearances of the digit 7 in any given non-negative integer.